# How to make custom Authentication filter that runs before [Authorize] and disables it if that custom auth succeeded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-5.0

I want to provide additional query string parameter authentication for some actions in some controllers. I want it to bypass [Authorize] but to use it if this custom query string authentication fails.

I've tried using IAuthorizationFilter with IOrderedFilter with Order = 0 but it seems in .net 3.1+ it's not working anymore.

Basically I want my filter to check for query string key, if this authentication fails it would pass the workflow to [Authorize] filter.

BUT if my custom Authentication filter would succeed - it should disable [Authorize] and go right to the action.

Comment: Are you putting credentials/api keys/tokens in the URL query? I'd highly advice against that. URLs are stored in browser history as well as forwarded to other sites your site might link to in the Referrer HTTP header. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: From your description, I assume you want to use two or more authentication methods to validate the request, and if any of these authentication method's success, it should be accessing the resource, right? If that is the case, you could validate it in the custom authentication, then add the custom authentication attribute at the header of the controller or action method, don't add the `[Authorize]` attribute. You could refer my reply in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66645141/authorization-mechanism-which-uses-jwt-token-or-api-key-in-net-core/66652956#66652956).

Answer (score 0):

The best option I discovered is to use Policies. In Policy I can check my custom authentication and if it does not work check if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) for default auth.

For your information. Custom filters did not work. IOverrideAuthorizationFilter is NOT part of asp.net core 3.1+, so don't go there.
Custom middleware does not give you opportunity to override authentication filters.

Best option is to use Policy. On this matter official Microsoft documentation does explanation well.